# How can i generate a token which will expire after some time just like the token field in password_reset table in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Password Reset Settings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the options for resetting passwords including the view
| that is your password reset e-mail. You can also set the name of the
| table that maintains all of the reset tokens for your application.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'password' => [
    'email' => 'emails.password',
    'table' => 'password_resets',
    'expire' => 60,
],
```

I want to generate a token just like the token in this password_resets table. But i don't understand how this is working.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store tokens in the DatabaseTokenRepository, you can use the `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\DatabaseTokenRepository` which implements the `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\TokenRepositoryInterface` interface. It is also registered as `'auth.password.tokens'`.

The create method has one required param to work. Here is the signature:

```
/**
 * Create a new token record.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
 * @return string
 */
public function create(CanResetPasswordContract $user);
```

This class is being used by the `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker` class that implements `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker` interface. Here, you can see an example usage of the repository.

Note: If you want to use the PasswordBroker, try `app()->make('auth.password')`.

Answer (score 1):

In `password_resets` table, there are three fields: `email,token,created_at`. When you generate a token, the date time is stored in `created_at` field. When you'll use this token, check if the token is older than you expiration time. If it is, then the token is invalid, else it's valid. Do your process, and destroy that token in either cases.

Comment: Then i have to do it implement it. i was just wondering if laravel have some helper for that ?

Comment: @rat as far as I know, there is no helper for this.